# Additional inner join modifying results of previous calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sqlplus

I am having issues with using the count() function in an sql plus query.. say if

```
    SELECT B.ID COUNT(S.BRANCH_ID) FROM BRANCH B 
    INNER JOIN STAFF S ON S.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
    GROUP BY B.ID;
```

from doing this I'll get the results

```
            b.id             count
             1                  6
             2                  6
             3                  6
             4                  7
             5                  6
```

which is fine.. However if I even add an extra inner join i'll get completely different and wrong results.. So if I put for example..

```
           SELECT COUNT(S.BRANCH_ID) FROM BRANCH B 
           INNER JOIN STAFF S ON S.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
           INNER JOIN TOOL_STOCK TS ON TS.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
           GROUP BY B.ID;
```

Now the results I get will be...

```
           b.id             count
            1                 96
            2                 96
            3                 96
            4                112
            5                 96
```

Why is this and how do I stop it? Cheers!

Comment: what exactly do you want to count? and what are the relationship between your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT B.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT S.STAFF_ID) FROM BRANCH B 
INNER JOIN STAFF S ON S.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN TOOL_STOCK TS ON TS.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
GROUP BY B.ID;
```

replacing S.STAFF_ID with the primary key field from the STAFF table.

Your problem is that the COUNT function returns the number of rows matching the GROUP BY clause after all rows have been joined and returned.

In your initial query you are finding the number of employees for each branch, In the second the number of employees is multiplied by the number of stock items.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the second join, you are getting the counts for STAFF + TOOLS at each branch.

You will likely need to add a subquery if you want all the data returned, but only counts of one record type.

I think the key to your issue is, which are you actually trying to count?